# Overwriting Image with same name - Django

Tags: python, django, overwrite

Through my project, I have users upload a profile picture. I save the profile picture as userID.jpg. If they upload a new profile picture, I want to overwrite the old profile picture, so I don't waste storage space. By browsing previously asked questions on stackoverflow, I redefined the OverwriteStorage:

```
class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        if self.exists(name):
             os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name))
        return name
```

When I upload the profile picture, I can see in the directory on my computer that the picture has been overwritten successfully.The image is saved with the path "media/profile/userID.jpg". However, when I display the image on my site, it is still the old picture. 
Through the Django site, when I open the path, I see the old picture, and when I try to change it through the admin, I get the following error:

```
[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: '\media\\profile\\userID.jpg'
```

I guess I am incorrectly overwriting the file and another instance is still open, and to solve it, I need to properly close the image before overwriting. I tried doing that, but to to no success.

Comment: Probably a cache by your browser. Did you tried reloading page using `ctrl + shift + r` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar but I used signals to update and delete images.

Firstable, I defined the name of the image in the `helpers.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from datetime import datetime

def upload_to_image_post(self, filename):
    """
    Stores the image in a specific path regards to date 
    and changes the name of the image with for the name of the post
    """    
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    current_date = datetime.now()

    return '%s/posts/main/{year}/{month}/{day}/%s'.format(
        year=current_date.strftime('%Y'), month=current_date.strftime('%m'), 
        day=current_date.strftime('%d')) % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename)
```

SO, I called the def in my model, specifically in the image's field

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from .helpers import upload_to_image_post

class Post(models.Model):
    """
    Store a simple Post entry. 
    """
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=200, help_text='Title of the post')
    body = models.TextField('Body', help_text='Enter the description of the post')   
    slug = models.SlugField('Slug', max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True, help_text='Title in format of URL')        
    image_post = models.ImageField('Image', max_length=80, blank=True, upload_to=upload_to_image_post, help_text='Main image of the post')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'
```

Finally, I defined signals to update or delete the image before the actions (update or delete) happen in the model.

```
import os
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete, pre_save
from .models import Post

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Post)
def post_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Deleting the specific image of a Post after delete it
    """
    if instance.image_post:
        if os.path.isfile(instance.image_post.path):
            os.remove(instance.image_post.path)

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Post)
def post_update(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Replacing the specific image of a Post after update
    """
    if not instance.pk:
        return False

    if sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).image_post:
        old_image = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).image_post
        new_image = instance.image_post
        if not old_image == new_image:
            if os.path.isfile(old_image.path):
                os.remove(old_image.path)
    else:
        return False
```

I hope, this helped you.

Comment: Thanks it works great now; however, I have never used signals before, and now my site is a bit slower. Is that normal? Is it better to put the signals in the models.py or in its own file?

Comment: are you saying your site is slow because of the signals? or your site was slow before that? I use signals and the performance is good.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting to [receive and process via signals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604272/273706). In some cases, it may be more convenient than `OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage)`.

But, `os.remove(filename)` is not safe/working without local filesystem. I recommend using [Django File Storage API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/files/storage/).

```py
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

os.path.isfile(path)  # worse
default_storage.exists(path)  # better

os.remove(path)  # worse
default_storage.delete(path)  # better
```

Answer (score -1):

Have it rename the old one to userID-old.jpg and then save userID.jpg. It will be quick that no one would likely notice it happening.