# Flask - Overwrite image using same name and display the new image

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, overwrite

I created a small flask website with 2 functions: upload pictures and display it on the website.

The website always saves newly uploaded images in the same name, `image.png`, to replace the previously uploaded image. When I upload a new file, it replaces the old file in the `static/img` directory successfully. However, the website keeps displaying the old image.

The closest problem I could find on stackoverflow was
[Overwriting Image with same name - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55603878/12257909). The answer here suggests using signals but didn't explain why this is happening. I'm hoping someone can clarify what I'm doing wrong if possible.

What can I do to make sure the newly uploaded image is displayed?

You can reproduce my situation using below information.

**Directory Structure**

```
├── main.py
├── static
│   └── img
│       └── image.png
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

#### main.py

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'static/img/'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['image'] 
        filename = "image.png"
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return render_template('index.html', filename=filename)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/<filename>')
def display_img(filename):
    """Display image on website"""
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename='img/' + filename))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

#### index.html

```html
<!-- Display Image -->
{% if filename %}
    <img src="{{ url_for('display_img', filename=filename) }}" alt="alt">
{% endif %}

<!-- Upload Image Button -->
<form action="#", method="POST", enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image"/>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This sounds like a cache-control issue. Look into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112316/using-flask-how-do-i-modify-the-cache-control-header-for-all-output/23115561#23115561) for some guidance. You can also try to using a `307` redirect with `return redirect(url_for('static', filename='img/' + filename), code=307)` inside `display_img`.

Comment: @Abdou Thank you! I disabled the cache on flask and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

As @Abdou mentioned in the comment above, the website was using the cached image to keep displaying the old image. Probably not the most optimal in most cases, but for this situation, disabling the cache by putting `app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0` on the top solved the problem.

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar but slightly different problem - When I overwrote my HTML templates, the old templates were still being Displayed.
Setting the [TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD) to True in the app.config solved the issue.

```
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
```